# Swift - How to check to see if sprite is assigned to certain image

Tags: swift, if-statement, sprite-kit

Currently, in my code, I have an SKSpriteNode named ball which randomly changes texture when it makes contact with anything. There are 4 different textures/images each with a different colored ball. I want to use an if else statement to check to see if the ball is equal to a specific texture so it can do an action.

I have this code so far, but it does not really check the texture of the ball sprite

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {


    if ball.texture == SKTexture(imageNamed: "ball2") && platform3.position.y <= 15 {

        print("Color is matching")

    } else {

        print("Not matching")
    }


}
```

The if platform3.position.y <= 25 part works, but the ball.texture part of the code does not check to see which texture the ball has.

Comment: This is failing because you are comparing an optional to a non-optional. When I run this code: `print(String(testChild.texture) + " == " + String(SKTexture(imageNamed: "Spaceship")))` it prints: `Optional(<SKTexture> 'Spaceship' (394 x 347)) == <SKTexture> 'Spaceship' (394 x 347)` which is false.

Comment: @Kendall no, this is failing because SKTexture(imageNamed:"ball2") creates a new texture every time, in spite of what docs says

Comment: I need it to check if the ball is assigned to a certain texture. I wasn't trying to create a new texture each time since the texture already exists, so how would I overcome this problem? @Knight0fDragon

Comment: @user6686513 look at all the answers people have provided

Answer (score 1):

Set user data when you assign the color to the ball.

```
ball.userData = ["color": 1]
// later you can check
if (ball.userData["color"] == 1) {
```

That is the proper way to do. Comparing integer will be faster.

Comment: comparing 2 pointers would be faster than what you are doing (That is true int comparison, you are pulling out of a dictionary)  His problem is creating a new texture every time

Answer (score 1):

### ColorType

You can use an enum to represent the possible colors

```
enum ColorType: String {
    case red = "redBall", green = "greenBall", blue = "blueBall", white = "whileBall"
}
```

The raw value of each enum case is the name of an image.

### Ball

Next declare your sprite class as follow. As you can see I am keeping track of the current `colorType`. Furthermore as soon as you change colorType, a new texture is assigned to the sprite

```
class Ball: SKSpriteNode {

    var colorType: ColorType {
        didSet {
            self.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: colorType.rawValue)
        }
    }

    init(colorType: ColorType) {
        self.colorType = colorType
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: colorType.rawValue)
        super.init(texture: texture, color: .clearColor(), size: texture.size())
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
let ball = Ball(colorType: .blue)
if ball.colorType == .blue {
    print("Is blue")
}
ball.colorType = .green
```

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: I finally followed your technique of linking a texture update to a property change with `didSet` ;-)